# Do the Separatist leaders know that Dooku was a Sith?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, attack-of-the-clones, darth-tyranus

Aside from General Griveous, in whom Tyranus trained, did the Separatist Leaders, specifically Viceroy Nute Gunray, Rune Haako, Poggle the Lesser, Wat Tambor, San Hill, Passel Argente, Shu Mai, Senator Po Nudo, and Senator Tikkes, know that Dooku was a Sith?

Comment: They thought he was merely the Count of Serenno and left the jedi order afaik, they may have known he was a Force user but more than that I don't think so. In fact, the general population of the Galaxy don't know the Sith exist or what they are.

Comment: I think poggle the lesser know that Dooku is a Sith

Comment: Why do you think that? Like I said, the Galaxy at large knows little of the Jedi and nothing of the Sith.

Comment: Because when dooku takes the death star from poggle the lesser,  he mentioned master. And that master is Darth sidious.

Comment: A blacksmith has a master, that doesn't make him a sith lord. He can report to a superior without knowing they are sith.

Comment: Nute Gunray knew that Darth Sidious was a Sith, didn't he?  It seems a reasonable guess that he also knew Dooku as Darth Tyranus, to ensure that he wouldn't question Dooku's authority over him, but I don't know whether there's any *direct* evidence in canon.

Answer (score 4):

**They probably put two and two together**. People killed on Mustafar by Vader were in contact with Lord Sidious since Episode 1. He explicitly mentioned Sith to them when he introduced Dath Maul as his apprentice ("Not for a Sith"). They were not total imbeciles, so they probably spent some time researching history and figuring what Sith were (1000 years is not that long even on Earth, we have lots of books about Romans for example) . Also, Sidious constantly mentions his apprentices (" I am sending you my new apprentice, Darth Vader. He will... take care of you.") . If Darth Vader was new apprentice, they must have known that old one existed. Was Dooku introduced as apprentice is unclear, but they knew he had Force powers (ex-Jedi master), and he also obeyed Sidious, therefore conclusion is clear from that. One thing that they probably didn't know is Dooku's Sith name (Darth Tyranus).